# Flurry missing context

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, flurry

I did add the following to my code as required by Flurry to work

```
#import "Flurry.h"
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [Flurry startSession:@"xxxxxxxxxx"];
}
```

And I did add the files "Flurry.h" and "libFlurry.a" to my project, however while building I get the error "Missing context for method declaration"

Do anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

I had used Flurry in my project and it worked fine. I guess its not working as its missing `FlurryAdDelegate.h` and `FlurryAds.h`. Add them up and check again.